# How do I get an image to go to the position of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I get an image to a div's position when it is cloned?

```js
$(".raindrop1").clone().removeClass("raindrop1").appendTo("body");
$("img").css({"left": "div".x, "top": "div".y});
```

```css
.shape{
border-radius: 50px;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "shape" onclick = "curse()"></div>
<img src = 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/raindrop-clipart-RTGdn5bTL.png' width = "15px" class = "raindrop1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Why not append cloned `img` to the `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example 1**

If you want to get the cloned `raindrop` to the `div's` position then you should just use `.appendTo(".shape")` that will insert the img, into the `div`

```js
$(".raindrop1").clone().removeClass("raindrop1").appendTo(".shape");
$("img").css({
  "left": "div".x,
  "top": "div".y
});
```

```css
.shape {
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape" onclick="curse()"></div>
<img src='http://images.clipartpanda.com/raindrop-clipart-RTGdn5bTL.png' width="15px" class="raindrop1">
```

**Example 2**

If you dont want to append it to the div, use can use the following code:

```
$("img:not(.raindrop1)").css({
  "left": $(".shape").position().left,
  "top": $(".shape").position().top,
  "position": "relative"
});
```

```js
$(".raindrop1").clone().removeClass("raindrop1").appendTo("body");
$("img:not(.raindrop1)").css({
  "left": $(".shape").position().left,
  "top": $(".shape").position().top,
  "position": "relative"
});
```

```css
.shape {
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape" onclick="curse()"></div>
<img src='http://images.clipartpanda.com/raindrop-clipart-RTGdn5bTL.png' width="15px" class="raindrop1">
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the position of the div you could use `let top = $("div").css("top")` and then set the values for your image `$("img").css("top",top)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgclone = targetdiv.clone()
    .offset({
    top: targetdiv.offset().top,
    left: targetdiv.offset().left
})
```

Comment: You should always leave an explanation about your suggestion and what it does / why to use it